# How do I determine the cause of Android app crash?

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat, aide-ide

I'm using [AIDE](http://www.android-ide.com/) to develop an Android app on my Nexus 7.  The logcat viewer doesn't work well because of changes to security in Jellybean (apps can no longer read each others log files).  My tablet is NOT rooted.

I started with a basic hello world, and have just edited the Main.Xml file to add some buttons to the layout.  However, the app now crashes as soon as I run.

How can I debug it to determine the cause?

Comment: Can you upload your xml file & activity file's code in question ?

Comment: I'm not looking for what the bug is, but how to determine any bug from the tablet, without using a pc

Comment: I dont think there is such a way to do same except developer is writing logs in .txt file, which you can view directly from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Hook your tablet to a PC via USB, then run "adb logcat" on the PC. This will let you see all of the logcat, on any version of Android.

Comment: Is there a way without connecting to a pc? I am doing dev on the tablet. Seems silly to connect to a pc to debug.

Comment: all that happens when I try this is "- waiting for device -", I have turned on dev mode

Comment: Be sure to turn on "USB debugging" in the developer options.

Comment: Got that, nice that they hid dev options away in an easter egg

Answer (score 0):

There is a *LogCat* in *AIDE*.

TRY:

```
Menu > View... > LogCat
```

> Sometimes LogCat not works on free versions, works fine on my Pro AIDE version